# how to show a blinking cursor on a hidden textbox as soon as it is visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a textbox which is initially hidden. But once when you click on a button it shows a textbox and i want the focus to automatically go to the textbox which is now visible. I want the cursor to start blinking there.
I tried autofocus but that did not work.

Comment: `document.getElementById("elementId").focus();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using visibility: hidden/opacity=0, you can show/hide by using display block/none.

Hope it will work :)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.span_click').click(function(){
    $('.show_search').addClass('visible_now');
        $('#set_focus').focus();
 });
});
```

```css
.show_search {
    background: #fff;
    //opacity: 0;
    display:none;
    padding: 0 30px;
    //visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: visibility 500ms ease 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: visibility 500ms ease 0.3s;
    -o-transition: visibility 500ms ease 0.3s;
    transition: visibility 500ms ease 0.3s
}
.visible_now {
    //opacity: 1;
    display:block;
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transition: visibility 500ms ease 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: visibility 500ms ease 0.3s;
    -o-transition: visibility 500ms ease 0.3s;
    transition: visibility 500ms ease 0.3s;
    z-index: 2
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="search_trigger" class="span_click"><span class="search_discovery">Search</span> </span>

<div class="show_search">
    <input class="" id="set_focus" type="search" placeholder="Search"/>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your HMTL is something like

```
<textarea id="ta"></textarea>
<button id="showta">Show the box</button>
```

then with jQuery

```
$('#showta').on('click',function(e){
    // display and focus
    $('#ta').show().focus();
});
```

with vanilla js

```
var ta = document.getElementbyId('ta'),
    btn = document.getElementbyId('showta');
btn.addEventListener( 'click', function(e){
    ta.style.display = 'block';
    ta.focus();
});
```

if it's not work, you might want to add a timeout for it. `var timeout = 100;` any number > 0. Then in handler:

```
clearTimeout(timeout);
timeout = setTimeout(function(){
    $('#ta').focus();
    // or ta.focus();
});
```

Comment: tried .focus but didnt work :( i could alert in the function to ensure that the function is working but focus did not work

Comment: thanks for this! this is working great in this case,is it the same case with visibility and opacity coming to picture
something like this one
https://jsfiddle.net/1769bgvf/3/

Answer (score 0):

After your button click, which shows the textbox, make your input element focus by

```
$('yourinputfiled').focus();
```

Thanks !